# Pass segments to variables in exp channel entry

Tags: channel-entries, entries, segments, url-title

I have the following structure:

A link - a href="/year/1991"> 1991 /a

And inside the YEAR template is this:   {exp:channel:entries channel="channel" limit="10" search:year_event_field="=1991"}
{title}

If I go to /year, it shows me the entries.

If I go to /year/1991 it doesn't it is showing me a blank page.

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if you have a four digits segment, EECMS will try to filter the entries by the year of their creation.

Try to set the `dynamic` parameter to `no`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess only experience and stackexchange can teach me this kind of things.